Word for a person who reveals truths about other people or a situation?
What's a word for an often controversial person who reveals truths about a person or situation that most other people don't?
I'm thinking something along the lines of "touchstone" (the jester in Shakespeare's As You Like It that revealed aspects of other characters that the other characters didn't).
I'm also thinking of "catalyst" (in the sense that the person indirectly, passively, or unintentionally reveals the truths; not "detractor", which would be to explicitly reveal the truths and damage reputation) or "whistleblower".

Are you specifically looking for a term with positive connotations? Obviously, there are many contexts where many / most people (or specifically, the people with most power) would have a very negative opinion of someone who voices certain "truths". The unvarnished truth is often not particularly welcome. But of course, it was part of the court jester's job to present unpalatable truths in a light-hearted way.

A truth speaker.

It sounds a bit medieval to me, but more particularly in recent decades, a [single word] truthsayer.

@Lambie No, I'm not looking for a word describing someone who actively speaks the truth about others, but someone whose living example itself reveals truths in others.

@FumbleFingers I'm neutral regarding positive/negative connotation.

"but whose life and example itself reveals truths in others"?? I don't think that means anything. Jesus was a living example but he didn't "reveal truth in others". I'm sure the Pope might agree.

@Lambie For example, an honest man who refrains from stealing $100 he sees on the sidewalk would reveal the truth that another man who does steal it is a thief, without the former having to explicitly speak the truth that the latter is a thief.

Perhaps the word you seek is exemplar. Please provide an example context sentence with blanks for the missing term, and make sure you paraphrase it so we know exactly what you want the sentence to mean when the target word is inserted.

I think that example you gave above is false. You bring together two individuals in a completely random way. The honest guy is just that: he is not dishonest. But the honest guy doesn't "show anything" about the other guy. He just does his thing.

Some possibly related phrases: honest to a fault, doesn't mince words.

Does whistle blower work for you? A derogatory description might be blabbermouth.

As per your example given in the comments: someone taking a $100 note from the ground is not necessarily a thief, and the only truth the other man reveals is that he himself did not pick it up. Still, I get what you mean. Does it have to be about virtue? Please provide an example sentence. I think FumbleFinger's option 'exemplar' is a good fit. I don't think there's a word that specifically points out, through a person's (in)action, the nature of an (in)action of another person, though.

It's theoretically possible that such a term would exist, just as there's an archetype of the wise fool, the fool who speaks the truth. So it's a valid question. Although it seems just that little bit too vague to merit a name, there may be a fictional character who does this and whose name has become proverbial.

I'm basically looking for a synonym of "Touchstone" as Shakespeare understood it.

What is wrong with touchstone?

@StuartF I'm not debating the validity, but the question should include a sample sentence all the same.
